# Trying to enable the button after validation

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Trying to enable the button on change event in kendo but it is not enabling the button can someone please help me to find what is happening

```
function onChange(){
    if($("#firstNameProperty").val()!=''&& $("#lastNameProperty").val()!='' && $("#emailField").val()!='' &&  $("#selectOwner").val()!='' && 
          $("#cprNumberProperty").val()!='' && $("#phoneField").val()!=''){
              console.log("enabled");
            $('#addToGrid').prop("disabled",false);

          }   
        else{
            console.log("disabled");
            $('#addToGrid').prop('disabled',true)
            
            
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Kendo UI for jQuery, you can do this to disable:

```
$("#addToGrid").addClass("k-state-disabled");
```

and to enable:

```
$("#addToGrid").removeClass("k-state-disabled");
```